About the anomaly of $R$-symmetry
We know that in 4d $\mathcal{N}=1$, we usually determine the real $R$-symmetry by declaring that it is not anomalous. However, in 2d $\mathcal{N}=(2,2)$, there is a genuine anomaly of $U(1)$ $R$-symmetry. For example, chap.9 of tachikawa's $4d~\mathcal{N}=1$ lecture notes uses it to determine the central charge of the Landau-Ginzburg models. How do we understand this?

I think the logic is as follows, which is not guaranteed to be true.
$4d~\mathcal{N}=1$ has the same amount of supercharges with $2d~\mathcal{N}=(2,2)$. The superconformal algebra for the $4d$ theory has a genuine $R$-symmetry. However, the superconformal algebra for the $2d$ theory is factorized into left-moving and right-moving parts and each part contains an $R$-symmetry current. Both of them are anomalous.
Now the $R$-symmetries of the two theories should match, since the $2d$ theory can be obtained by dimensional reduction of the $4d$ theory, and the dimensional reduction should not break the internal symmetries.
Thus we should not indeed have two $R$-symmetries in $2d$, so they must be anomalous. We can also combine these two $R$-symmetries to cancel the anomaly. That is, we really have one and only one quantum $R$-symmetry in $2d$, the same amount of that of the $4d$ theory.
